# How can I resolve pydocstyle error "D205: 1 blank line required between summary line and description (found 0)"?

Tags: python, docstring

I'm trying to use pydocstyle to check the quality of my docstring and I'm getting this error:

`D205: 1 blank line required between summary line and description (found 0)`

This is how my code looks like

```
def func(input):
    """

    Function that does something interesting.
        Args:
            -input- Input of the function

    Returns:
        output- Output of the function

    """
    data = words + sentences
    corpus= somefunction(data)
```

When I put a blank line between the docstring and the function statements like so;

```
def func(input):
    """

    Function that does something interesting.
        Args:
            -input- Input of the function

    Returns:
        output- Output of the function

    """

    data = words + sentences
    corpus= somefunction(data)
```

I get the this errror:

`D202: No blank lines allowed after function docstring (found 1)`

How do I resolve this? Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 21):

See [PEP 257 -- Docstring Conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/)

```
def func(input):
    """**summary line, max. 79 chars including period** Do something interesting.

    **description starts after blank line above**
    Args:
        -input- Input of the function

    Returns:
        output- Output of the function

    """
    # no blank line allowed here

    data = [words, sentences]
    corpus = somefunction(data)
```

Comment: @Lutaaya The summary line should be `one` line, followed by a `blank` line.

Answer (score 4):

**To Solve this, add a blank line after the first line of the Docstring.**

According to [PEP 257 -- Docstring Conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/), a [Multi-line docstring](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#id17) consists of a **Summary line**(1st line) just like a [one-line docstring](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#id16), followed by a **blank line** and then a more **Elaborate description** follows. It is important that the summary line fits on one line and is separated from the rest of the docstring by a blank line.

```py
def func(input):
    """Function that does something interesting.

    Args:
        - input - Input of the function

    Returns:
        - output - Output of the function
    """
    data = words + sentences
    corpus = somefunction(data)
```

**Note**

- The *Summary line* can begin on the same line as the opening quotes or on the next line, preferably, the former.
- There should be **no blank lines** after the opening quotes or before the closing quotes.

[Read More...](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#what-is-a-docstring)

Answer (score 0):

Making a python script simultaneously adhere to `pydocstyle` and `pycodestyle` is a challenge. But one thing which greatly helps is that in your docstring write the first line as summary of the function or class within 79 characters including `.`. This way you adhere to both PEP 257 (as per `pydocstyle`) of having a period at the end of an unbroken line and 79 characters limit of PEP 8 (as per `pycodestyle`).

Then after leaving one blank line (for that using new line shortcut of your code editor is better than manually pressing `enter`) you can write whatever you want and at that time focusing only on `pycodestyle` which is slightly easier than `pydocstyle` and the main reason is that **our understanding of line and indentation is quite different than what system understands due to indentation settings, tab settings, line settings in the various code editors we use**.So in this way you will have `TODO` from `pycodestyle` which you can understand and rectify easily instead of banging your head against the wall on `pydocstyle` mysterious`TODO`s of 1 blank line, which you see is there but the system doesn't recognize.