# How can I resolve flake8 error "D205: 1 blank line required between summary line and description"?

Tags: python, docstring, flake8

I'm trying to use flake8(pydocstyle) to check the quality of my docstring and I'm getting this error:

D205: 1 blank line required between summary line and description
This is how my code looks like
Exemple:

```
    def func(
        self,
        source: str,
    ) -> str:
        """
        Generates an sql query for a temporary table by searching 
        the source code in the rules and restrictions table for these sources.

        Args:
            source: data source code

        Returns:
            sql query for creating a table

        """
        sql = None
```

A long message that is difficult to separate.
And max line length = 100
How to transfer a sentence to another line correctly? Or is it easier to ignore the error on such cases?

I tried to divide, but the meaning is a little lost.
So far only so

```
# noqa D205 1 blank line required between summary line and description
```

Comment: personally I find pydocstyle to be a waste of time -- but what it wants you to have is a short one-line summary which fits in N characters (on the opening `"""`), and then a blank line and then a further description

Comment: See [How can I resolve pydocstyle error "D205: 1 blank line required between summary line and description"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50924700/how-can-i-resolve-pydocstyle-error-d205-1-blank-line-required-between-summary/50926438#50926438)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, lots of well-known packages don't pass all the rules in `flake8`, `numpy` for instance. Don't be so harsh on yourself. If you really want to solve this annoying problem, here's some solutions.

First solution: add a summary comment after `"""` and add a space line between summary and desc.

```
def func(
        self,
        source: str,
) -> str:
    """Generate a sql query

    Generates an sql query for a temporary table by searching
    the source code in the rules and restrictions table for these sources.

    summary

    Args:
        source: data source code

    Returns:
        sql query for creating a table

    """
    sql = None
```

Second solution: force to ignore `D205` by editing `.flake8`

Comment: the second "solution" isn't a solution -- that puts a weird blank line in the middle of the sentence when rendered